# Assigning output to variable and joining/concatenating them in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli, aws-codepipeline

I have a buildspec that is part of a CodePipeline that exports to a bucket, but I **need that bucket name to be passed in as a string** with the pulled account number.

I have the account number successfully pulled, but I can't seem to pass it in to a variable (`accountnum`) nor can I get the string (`lambdaapibucket`) to join with the pulled `accountnum` to become one string/bucket name.

Here's the latest iteration of my attempts. I have tried so many different things at this point, including backticks, quotes with exit parameters, with and without echos, piping, and who knows what else I've forgotten. Thank you in advance for any ideas or points in the right direction.

```
- ACCOUNTNUM= aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query 'Account'
- LambdaAPIBucket= echo lambdaapibucket-
- LambdaAPIBucketName= concat([$LambdaAPIBucket]  + [$ACCOUNTNUM])
- export BUCKET=LambdaAPIBucketName
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out, if anyone later on needs the answer. For the variables, the back ticks need to be done as below, and then the joining of the variables is done with them as one continuous string, no need to attach them and then assign them separately into a variable:

```
- ACCOUNTNUM=`aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query 'Account'`
- LambdaAPIBucket=`echo lambdaapibucket-`
- export BUCKET=$LambdaAPIBucket$ACCOUNTNUM
```